# Java Selenium WebDriver IE 9 - NoSuchElementException WARNING:The Server did not provide any stacktrace information

Tags: java, webdriver, nosuchelementexception

Using Selenium 2.45 and IE 9

Chrome and Firefox operate correctly within the Cross Browser tool but IE 9 is throwing this error. I have updated the Security Settings and Ensured all were Enabled and Set to the same security setting. I have also updated the Status bar to 100%. Not sure what to do at this point.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkvbb.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wIUj.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dks9j.png)

Comment: Does that work at all?

Comment: Yes, I added Pictures so I am not sure why they weren't showing. Basically my code runs fine in Chrome and Firefox, but even after adjusting the security settings IE still throws this error. If it weren't working in the other environments i would check my code but since its using the same code and runs fine in the other two environmetns not sure what else to do.

Comment: You mean works on different machines?

Comment: I only have this one machine to run the code on. Sorry, but any other suggestions would be welcomed!

Comment: You need to provide more information, about this element, for example it's html code, and the coe you are using in the test. Did you press F12 in IE and examine this element, and also did you compare it's html code on IE with Chrome/FF ? Maybe it is rendered diferently by the SUT depending on the browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security settings had to be set to 'Medium" not high or low. That solved it!

Thank you all for your help in the matter!

Answer (score -1):

you should check or uncheck ALL "protection mode" checkers at your ie settings.